# IIS 503 error for App Pool user after reboot, unless App Pool identity set as Administrator

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

After a reboot of a *Windows 2008 R2* server, one particular *App Pool* stopped functioning and a **503 error** is produced.

This *App Pool* runs as a specific user

- The user account has not changed and the password has not changed
- Am able to login to the server via RDP using the user / pass
- Created a new *App Pool* with this user as the Identity, but produces the same 503 error message

If I change the account this run under to be an Administrator of the server, it works. Also, if I change from the user to **ApplicationPoolIdentity** is works as well.

The following settings of the App Pool are different from a default value

- Managed Pipeline Mode: Classic
- Identity: The username the app pool is running as
- Load User Profile: False

Without being set as an Administrator, the error message is specifically

> Application pool ASP.NET v2.0 Classic has been disabled. Windows
>   Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started
>   a worker process to serve the application pool.

Does anyone have an idea of what may be causing this after a reboot and requiring this user to be an Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the account running the app pool is in the IIS_IUSRS group in User Manager   (lusrmgr.msc)

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the response, but sadly, I just checked and it's part of IIS_IUSRS.